# How can I get the resources under Mac OSX like windows?

Tags: macos

In windows I can get the resources by using the below method:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

[image]

How can I get the resources under Mac OSX ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution.

1.Finder <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> -> Go to Server.

2.Then type in the server address.

3.Connect it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same goal doing as follows:

`Finder -> Go Menu -> Connect to Server`